# Chrome displays body before head scripts are finished

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tags, rendering

From what I knew, the browser suppose to stop rendering DOM whenever it reaches a script, until the scripts are completed.

However, if I write a

```
window.open('Mypage.aspx?ID=0', '_top');
```

at the head tag I can still see a quick 'flicker' before the new page is opened.
I even tried to create an artificial delay before the body tag but to no avail.
How can I avoid that flicker?

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>aa</title>
<script type="text/javascript">window.open('MyPage.aspx?ID=0', '_top');

 var now = new Date().getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() < now + 3000){ /* force delay */ } 

</script></head><body style="background-color:red">
initial page
</body>
```

Comment: In lieu of anything more sophisticated, you could set `display:none` on your body style, then show it or fade it in at any point you so choose.

Comment: @ne1410s - When document's body big enough, unfortunately it doesn't work - If I change text inside body tag to a 4 MB text length for example - it still flickers :( –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome you could use `window.stop();` in the first line of your script which will stop html rendering.

Although for me it seems more consistent to manage it with css classes to hide/show the  when it's appropiate.

Comment: Hiding with css classes didn't work for me in Chrome, but window.stop() did. I just modified it to `if (typeof window.stop=='function'){window.stop();};` to prevent error on IE which doesn't support window.stop().